# Homeomorphism between $X = \left\{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3} ; x^{2}+y^{2}=1\right\}$ and $S^{2}-\{(0,0,1),(0,0,-1)\}$ and

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Show that $X = \left\{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3} ; x^{2}+y^{2}=1\right\}$ is homeomorphic to  $S^{2}-\{(0,0,1),(0,0,-1)\}$.

I've been trying to define an $f$ using something with $\cos(x)$ or $\sin(y)$, but I couldn't find anything close to an homeomorphism.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Break the problem into 2 steps. Use a cylinder that is only between $(-1,1)$ in the z coordinate as an intermediate. Then you can write $f = g \circ h$.

Comment: Or try to adapt the [Stereographic Projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection) to this problem

Comment: As mentionned above, you can do some kind of projection. In fact if you use the embeddings of $X$ and $Y := S^2 \setminus \{ (0,0,1), (0, 0, -1) \}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, a homeomorphism can be given by $f: X \to Y: x \mapsto \frac{x}{\|x\|}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on AHusain's comment, we can do the following: Define $h : S^2 \setminus \{(0,0,1),(0,0,-1)\} \to S^1 \times (-1,1)$ by
$$
h(x,y,z) := \left( \frac{x}{d}, \frac{y}{d}, z \right),
$$
where $d = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. You can check that this is indeed a homeomorphism. Next, define a function $g : S^1 \times (-1,1) \to X$ by
$$
g(x,y,z) := \left( x,y, \frac{2}{\pi}\arctan(z) \right).
$$
Again, you can check that this defines a homeomorphism. Then we let $f := g \circ h$, i.e. we get a homeomorphism $S^2 \setminus \{(0,0,1),(0,0,-1)\} \cong X$. Explicitly, $f$ looks like
$$
f(x,y,z) = \left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, \frac{2}{\pi}\arctan(z) \right).
$$
Hope this helps!